# Can I say that every integrable function is measurable?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, proof-writing, examples-counterexamples, measurable-functions

Let $(X, \mathcal S, \mu)$ be a measure space. Let $\Bbb L$ be the collection of all $\mathcal S$-measurable functions and let $L_1(\mu)$ be the collection of all $\mu$-integrable functions i.e. the collection of all the functions $f : X \longrightarrow \Bbb R^*$ such that $\int f^+\ d\mu < +\infty$ and $\int f^-\ d\mu < +\infty,$ where $f^+$ and $f^-$ respectively denote the positive part and the negative part of the function $f.$ Now suppose that $f \in L_1(\mu).$ Can we say that $f \in \Bbb L?$ What I know is that if $f \in \Bbb L$ and $\int f^+\ d\mu, \int f^-\ d\mu < +\infty$ then $f \in L_1(\mu).$ Is the converse true?

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally $L_1(\mu)$ is defined to be the collection of all _measurable_ functions with $\int f^+ d\mu < \infty$ and $\int f^- d\mu < \infty$, so it's usually contained in the definition because if $f$ is not measurable, then $\int f^+ d\mu$ is not necessarily defined.

Comment: @user6247850 $:$ But my book doesn't say it explicitly. It only says that a function $f : X \longrightarrow \Bbb R^*$ is said to be $\mu$-integrable if $\int f^+\ d\mu$ and $\int f^-\ d\mu$ exist and are both finite. Then we define $$\int f\ d\mu := \int f^+\ d\mu - \int f^-\ d\mu.$$

Comment: Which book are you using?

Comment: I am following the lecture notes on *Measure and Integration* given to us by our instructor at our institute. This notes is actually based on the book written by Inder K. Rana.

Comment: There are conventions where not every integral function need be measurable, this kind of a thing can happen when you have a measure and then define the integral to not care about what happens inside of measure zero sets. Doing it like this spares time, since you do not need to define the completion of a measure (the integrable functions will be measurable wrt the completion of the measure). However in standard convention every integrable function needs to be measurable, so even if your course has a different definition in your life after the course you must always demand measurability.

Comment: It will be interesting to look on not measurable function, but integrable.

Comment: @s.harp nice answer!

Comment: @zkutch let $A$ be some measure zero set and $B\subseteq A$ non-measurable. Then the characteristic function of $B$ is integrable but not measurable with these conventions. Note that if the measure is complete this situation is impossible. A more concrete example would be to look at some set $X$ with $\sigma$ algebra $\{\emptyset, X\}$ and measure $\mu(X)=0$. Then the only measurable functions are the constant ones, but every function is integrable (with integral $0$).

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Remember how the integral was defines. First for simple and of course measurable functions. measurability is necessary here or course. Then, for positive (measurable) functions, you basically construct a sequence of simple measurable functions using preimages of the positive functions. This is where -maybe silently- the measurability condition is used.