# What is the importance of the measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ and the measurability of $f$ in the definition of integral?

Tags: measure-theory, definition, lebesgue-integral

Let $f:\Omega\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}_{+}$ be a nonnegative measurable function on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$. The integral of $f$ with respect to $\mu$ is defined as:
\begin{align*}
\int fd\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_{n}d\mu
\end{align*}

where $\{f_{n}\}_{n\geq 1}$ is any sequence of nonnegative simple functions such that $f_{n}(\omega)\uparrow f(\omega)$ for all $\omega$.

**MY QUESTION**

What is the importance of the measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ and the measurability of $f$ in the proposed definition?

As far as I have understood, we need a domain, which is given by $\Omega$; we need a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ in order to properly define the simple functions $f_{n}$; and we need the measure $\mu$ in order to integrate each $f_{n}$ so that we can take the limit.

Am I missing something? Please let me know if it is the case.

Comment: So you already answered what the importance of the measure space is by saying why and what we need all of $\Omega, \mathcal F, $ and $\mu$ for. We need the measurability of $f$ so that a sequence of simple functions $f_n$ with $f_n \nearrow f$ always exists.

Comment: take a look at the strongly related question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3734544/can-i-say-that-every-integrable-function-is-measurable

Comment: it is a consequence of the definition of the integral for simple functions, that is, to define $\int f_n d\mu$ you need that $f_n$ would be measurable. From there it follow that $f$ is also measurable.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!